# error: method updateChildren in class DatabaseReference cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My English is bad. I can't solve this problem. I do not know how to change the code to make everything work:

[image]

```
RootRef.child("Users").child(phone).updateChildren(userDataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

```
  required: Map<String,Object>,CompletionListener
  found:    HashMap<String,Object>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

My code:

```
typpackage com.example.remont_okon;

import static java.util.Collections.*;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.service.autofill.UserData;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button registerbutton;
    private EditText usernameinput,phoneinput,passwordinput;
    private ProgressDialog loandingbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        registerbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        usernameinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username_input);
        phoneinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_phone_input);
        passwordinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_input);
        loandingbar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreateAccount();
            }
        });


    }

    private void CreateAccount() {
        String username = usernameinput.getText().toString();
        String phone = phoneinput.getText().toString();
        String passsword = passwordinput.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите Имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите Телефон", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(passsword)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loandingbar.setTitle("Создание аккаунта");
            loandingbar.setMessage("Пожалуйста подождите");
            loandingbar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loandingbar.show();

            ValidatePhone(username,phone,passsword);
        }

    }

    private void ValidatePhone(final String username, final String phone, final String passsword) {
        final DatabaseReference RootRef;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists()))
                {
                    HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userDataMap.put("phone", phone );
                    userDataMap.put("name", username );
                    userDataMap.put("password", passsword );

                    RootRef.child("Users").child(phone).updateChildren(userDataMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                loandingbar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Регистрация прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(loginIntent);

                            } else {
                                loandingbar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Регистрация не прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Номре" + phone + "Уже зарегестрирован", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loandingbar.dismiss();
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have already installed updates and downgraded versions of packages. At the moment, my gradle file looks like this.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    // Add the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.remont_okon'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.remont_okon"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.ibm.watson:ibm-watson:7.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'annotations'
    }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the following line of code:

```
RootRef.child("Users").child(phone).updateChildren(userDataMap).addOnCompleteListener(/*.../*);
```

The [DatabaseReference#updateChildren(@NonNull Map<String, Object> update)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,java.lang.Object%3E)) takes an argument of type `Map<String, Object>`. The `userDataMap` object is defined as:

```
HashMap<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
//
```

Which is HashMap, not a Map, hence the error. To solve this, you need to simply change the type of the object like this:

```
Map<String, Object> userDataMap = new HashMap<>();
//
```

And your error will be gone.

Comment: Hey Дархан. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?